# How do you add a Filter to embedded jetty?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using jetty's proxy server (from `jetty-proxy`) and don't know how to use it and how to add Filters

Comment: Maybe something like 

Server server = new Server(8080);

    ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
    server.setHandler(handler);

    handler.addServletWithMapping(YourServlet.class, "/*");
    handler.addFilterWithMapping(YourFilter.class, "/*",
        EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way:
find you class `ProxyServer`,then add this:

```
 ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
FilterHolder fh = handler.addFilterWithMapping(MyFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
context.addFilter(fh, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
```

Comment: Don't use `ServletHandler` directly, that's an internal class.  It's meant to be used as a specific Servlet (or Filter) entry from a `ServletContextHandler` (which manages the collection of `ServletHandlers`)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt so, what's the right way?

Comment: See [Jetty Embedded Cookbook / AddFilterMultipleMapping](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/jetty-10.0.x/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/AddFilterMultipleMapping.java)